# Play You tube video by passing url in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, video

I have a textbox where user enters the URLs of the you tube video's (in the back-end of my custom plugin). Now what I want to do on the front end is to display that video using that URL.

I used both **iframe** and **video tag** but both do not plays the video.

*Using Video tag I get this message :* 
*'No video with supported format and MIME type found'* in ***Firefox*** and in ***Chrome*** get only black screen and no audio.

*Is there any solution that can be done without using JavaScript or Jquery.*

*Using Iframe nothing appears :*
On inspecting I get iframe with src but nothing appears in *body tag*

*This is the input type where video's url is added:*

```
<input id="video" name="video" type="text" style="width: 95%"
value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['video'])?>" size="50" class="code" >
```

*And this is how I'm fetching it from db and passing it to the video and iframe tags :*

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="<?php echo $video[0];?>" type="video">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="<?php echo $video[0];?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```

I have taken multiple urls and exploded it using ',' operator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share more code. Sounds like the input should only be clean youtube link and then you can echo out the youtube iframe interface with php wordpress.

EDIT:
youtube iframe should be like this:

```
    <iframe class="youtube" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u-KqDVNowKU"
allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" style="height: 405px;"></iframe>
```

I use this js for the size of the iframe on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$('.youtube').css('height',Math.floor($('.youtube').width() * 0.5625)+'px');
});
```

Comment: I have edited my post, and added the code. So you can check it.

Comment: Ok thanks, have you made sure the src is correct for the youtube iframe interface? If it's not showing, make sure the iframe is set to show, display:block or z-index:123 or something, it should be shown.

Comment: ok, you need the embed youtube link for iframe. Write a replace function to make it work ;)

Comment: If you can help me with it as well. It would be so kind of you :)